# Contact Form 7 Required field not working

Tags: contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 for a number of forms on my site.

I am using almost identical code for two forms.

The problem is, on one form, i am missing 'required field' messages, loading animation on send and the success message.

However, my other forms are working perfectly.

The not working properly form can be found here (just click on any button):
http://trailerbins2u.com.au/

The Code for this form is:

```
<div class="thrive-col left-col">
[text* your-name placeholder "Name*"][text your-company placeholder "Company"]</div> 
<div class="thrive-col right-col">
[email* your-email placeholder "Email*"]
[tel* your-phone placeholder "Phone Number*"]</div>
[text* your-address placeholder "Drop Off Address*"]</div> 
[date* your-drop placeholder "Trailer Drop Off Date*"]</div>
[text* your-time placeholder "Preferred Time*"]
[select* your-trailer "Select Trailer Size*" "4 Cubic Metre Lite" "4 Cubic Metre" "5 Cubic Metre" "6 Cubic Metre"]
<div class="thrive-col left-col"><label>Do You Have Household Rubbish?</label>
[checkbox* your-household-rubbish "Household Junk" "Furniture & Furnishings" "Appliances & Whitegoods" "Paper & Stationary" "Office Waste & E-waste" "Rugs & Flooring" "Packaging Waste" "Green Waste" "Mattress" "None of the Above"]</div>
<div class="thrive-col right-col"><label>Do you have Construction Waste?</label>
[checkbox* nl default:10 your-construction-rubbish "Plasterboard (Gyprock)" "Timber & Framing" "Joinery & Cabinets" "Timber Flooring" "Carpet & Underlay" "Packaging Waste" "Builders Rubble" "Kitchen Demolition" "Bathroom Demolition" "None of the Above"]</div>
[textarea your-message placeholder "Your Message"] 
[submit "Send"]
```

My other, perfectly working form can be found here (again, click on any button):
http://trailerbins2u.com.au/rubbish-removal-sydney/

And the code:

```
<div class="thrive-col left-col">
[text* your-name placeholder "Name*"] [text your-company placeholder "Company"]</div> 
<div class="thrive-col right-col">[email* your-email placeholder "Email*"]
[tel* your-phone placeholder "Phone Number*"]</div> 
[date* your-drop placeholder "Date Removal Required"]
[text* your-time placeholder "Time*"]
[text* your-address placeholder "Address*"]
<div class="thrive-col left-col"><label>Do You Have Household Rubbish?</label>
[checkbox* your-household-rubbish "Household Junk" "Furniture & Furnishings" "Appliances & Whitegoods" "Rugs & Flooring" "Packaging Waste" "Green Waste" "Mattress" "None of the Above"]</div>
<div class="thrive-col right-col"><label>Do you have Construction Rubbish?</label>
[checkbox* your-construction-rubbish "Plasterboard (Gyprock)" "Timber & Framing" "Joinery & Cabinets" "Timber Flooring" "Carpet & Underlay" "Packaging Waste" "Builders Rubble" "Kitchen Demolition" "Bathroom Demolition" "None of the Above"]</div>
[textarea your-message placeholder "Your Message"]  
[submit "Send"]
```

So as you can see, the code is almost identical. Contact forms 7 is obviously working properly for the second form to send, and no css should be affecting it, as it should affect both.

Any ideas on what's gone wrong?

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to an extra form tag placed before the short code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).